# HTML form, sets of data, datastructure interpretation

Tags: html, rest

I have a form that is dynamically generated.  Containing recurring lists of hidden fields, that represent selections within my application.

A form would typically look something like this:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="key1" value="value1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="key1_option" value="option1"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="key2" value="value1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="key2_option" value="option2"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is there a better way to do something like this?

The main difficulty I am facing is that you lose the logical grouping of the fieldsets when you submit the form and try to interpret the input on the backend.

Comment: If your server side uses PHP you can do something like `name="key[1]",name="option[1]"`, `name="key[2]",name="option[2]"`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic behind the HTML structure will be lost of course, the only information transmitted is what's inside the form-tag. But I guess you already know that.

Why don't you use arrays to name your variables?

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="keyset[0][key]" value="value1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="keyset[0][option]" value="option1"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="keyset[1][key]" value="value1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="keyset[1][key]" value="option2"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is there a reason you group your items like that?

Comment: Each fieldset represents an input within my application, each of those inputs can have different options.  This structure would be what is sent to the backend.  As it has only the relevant information.  I like the array approach.  Would this be a standard way of doing things ?

Comment: Standard, yes, since this way you can keep your information grouped. This would basicly be a discussion about arrays vs single variables. Do you have access to the backend?

Comment: Yes I do, this would indeed be a more consistent way to parse the input.